# What is a basis for this extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra

What would be a basis for: 
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}e^{2i\pi/3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Now $e^{2i\pi/3} = \sqrt[3]{2}(-\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt3}{2})    $

One vector is $1$ , would the other vector be $ \sqrt[3]{2}(-\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt3}2)$ or just $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}e^{2\pi i/3})$.

Answer (score 1):

As anon's comment to the question indicates, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2e^{2i\pi/3})$ is not an extension field of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ since it does not contain $\sqrt[3]2$; therefore the question is ill formulated. I'll assume either that you meant it as an extension of $\Bbb Q$, or that you meant the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,e^{2i\pi/3})$ instead.

For the first interpretation, your element $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2e^{2\pi\mathbf i/3}$ satisfies $\alpha^3=2$, and since $X^3-2$ is irreducible over$~\Bbb Q$, that is its minimal polynomial. The field is then isomorphic of $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^3-2)$, and a basis over $\Bbb Q$ is formed by $\{\alpha^0,\alpha^1,\alpha^2\}$. The field is also isomorphic to the subfield $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ of $\Bbb R$.

For the second interpretation, you just have the extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ by the element $\mathbf j=e^{2i\pi/3}$ satisfying $1+\mathbf j+\mathbf j^2=0$. Then $\{1,\mathbf j\}$ is a basis of the field extension.